# Redo thread getting blocked while capturing index physical stats

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019, index-maintenance

Noticed REDO thread getting blocked for the whole period of running following query, what could be the reason? It is on SQL Server 2019 CU21,

The blocking was for almost more than 1hr+, for the entire period the physical stats on that DB is done. And, the blocked resource is on the same object, curious why it is only one specific object when the index fragmentation stats collection is happening across all objects in that DB.

Can this be controlled or avoided to not keep the redo fall behind for such long duration?

Query:

```
    INSERT INTO #index_fragmentation_log
SELECT GETDATE() AS [LogDate],
       DB_NAME() AS [DatabaseName],
       SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS [SchemaName],
       OBJECT_NAME(ips.object_id) AS [TableName],
       i.name AS [IndexName],
       i.type_desc AS [IndexType],
       p.partition_number AS [PartitionNumber],
       ips.alloc_unit_type_desc AS [AllocUnitTypeDesc],
       ROUND(ips.avg_fragmentation_in_percent, 2) AS [AvgFragmentationInPercent],
       ips.fragment_count AS [FragmentCount],
       ROUND(ips.page_count * 8 / 1024, 2) AS [IndexSizeMB],
       p.[rows] AS [Rows],
       i.fill_factor AS [FillFactor],
       p.data_compression AS [DataCompression],
       NULL AS [Status],
       NULL AS [ExceptionLog]
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS ips
    JOIN sys.indexes AS i
        ON ips.object_id = i.object_id
           AND ips.index_id = i.index_id
    JOIN sys.partitions AS p
        ON ips.object_id = p.object_id
           AND i.index_id = p.index_id
           AND ips.partition_number = p.partition_number
    JOIN sys.objects AS o
        ON ips.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE ips.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0.0
      AND ips.index_type_desc NOT IN ( 'HEAP' )
      AND o.schema_id IN ( SCHEMA_ID('dbo'));
```

Blocking Details:

| session_id | command | blocking_session_id | wait_time | wait_type | wait_resource |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | DB STARTUP | 0 | 43 | REDO_THREAD_PENDING_WORK |  |
| 33 | DB STARTUP | 0 | 59 | REDO_THREAD_PENDING_WORK |  |
| 37 | DB STARTUP | 1843 | 2564627 | LCK_M_X | OBJECT: 9:309576141:15 |
| 38 | DB STARTUP | 0 | 74 | REDO_THREAD_PENDING_WORK |  |
| 48 | DB STARTUP | 0 | 61 | REDO_THREAD_PENDING_WORK |  |
| 190 | DB STARTUP | 0 | 105 | REDO_THREAD_PENDING_WORK |  |
| 195 | DB STARTUP | 0 | 12 | REDO_THREAD_PENDING_WORK |  |

Details the DB fall behind because of Redo thread blocked.

| database_name | recovery_lsn | truncation_lsn | last_hardened_lsn | last_received_lsn | last_redone_lsn | last_redone_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| db01 | 4656563000100725600001 | 4656602000033369600004 | 4656602000039955200001 | 4656602000039954400001 | 4656602000039947200042 | 2024-01-19 18:15:45.363 |
| db02 | 87431000001092000001 | 87445000001880800001 | 87445000001892800001 | 87445000001892000001 | 87445000001892000001 | 2024-01-19 18:15:28.773 |
| blocked_db03 | 271295000189302400001 | 271577000159532800001 | 271579000053756000001 | 271579000053755200001 | 271577000176204800080 | 2024-01-19 17:24:56.883 |

Comment: Clearly SQL Server is showing its disapproval for you looking at index fragmentation.

Comment: If it's getting blocked, you should have a lock_redo_blocked event with information. That'd be something useful to add to the question.

Comment: If it's saying the `blocking_session_id` is 1843, it would be nice if you showed us what that session is doing too. [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) is a better tool to look at what's running and being blocked, with more succinct details. In any case, I agree with Erik and hope you're not trying to analyze index fragmentation.

Comment: @J.D. 1843 is the query capturing physical stats which I have it there.

Comment: same query was executed on 20+ databases but out of all I have noticed that blocking happened only on 2 DBs for the entire period of query completion.

Comment: @SivaDasari "*1843 is the query capturing physical stats which I have it there*" - Yes, so you've said. Would be helpful to see execution information about that `session_id` though. Anyway I'd highly recommend [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) either way.

Comment: Redo is blocked because it can't get a lock on the indexes you're scanning. Seems straight forward.

Comment: Blocking existed for the entire period the whole DB is done and the wait resource didn’t even change, it is on the same object. 
When checked on primary replica there isn’t much activity on that object, it is minimal to normal workload. It took almost an hr+ to complete the DB and the DB has fall behind with redo the whole period.

Answer (score 0):

Figured from Microsoft documentation, it is an expected case when queriying [sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#:%7E:text=If%20you%20query,table%20or%20view.) on secondary replica.

> If you query sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats on a server instance that
> is hosting an availability group readable secondary replica, you might
> encounter a REDO blocking issue. This is because this dynamic
> management view acquires an IS lock on the specified user table or
> view that can block requests by a REDO thread for an X lock on that
> user table or view.

So, my primary concern was the blocking duration,

- Blocking persisted for the 'full length' of the index statistics
  collection operation for that specific database.
- This has impacted our RTO for our secondary replica.
- Also, an increased version store in tempdb impacted performance for our read-only workload.

Solution I have in place is,

- Gathering metrics specifically for each object (`object_id`), index (`index_id`) and partition (`partition_number`) as opposed to the entire database, *thus making the capture process short lived*.
- Although it increased the total runtime as each index is done sequentially, *this approach significantly decreased the intensity of the blocking impact on user workload*.

Ex:

```
DECLARE @index_id INT = 1,
        @partition_number INT = 1
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
    (DB_ID(N'Test'), OBJECT_ID(N'Person.Address'), @index_id, @partition_number, NULL);
GO
```

Tempdb Version Store: DB level capture vs Object level capture.

[image]